# Java applet is being fetched repeatedly

Tags: java

I have an applet that in one specific environment gets fetched in a loop.
This causes timeouts and failures.
This is the log from the console:

```
    Java Plug-in 11.201.2.09 x86
    Using JRE version 1.8.0_201-b09 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
    User home directory = C:\Users\User
    ----------------------------------------------------
    c:   clear console window
    f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
    g:   garbage collect
    h:   display this help message
    l:   dump classloader list
    m:   print memory usage
    o:   trigger logging
    q:   hide console
    r:   reload policy configuration
    s:   dump system and deployment properties
    t:   dump thread list
    v:   dump thread stack
    x:   clear classloader cache
    0-5: set trace level to <n>
    ----------------------------------------------------
    basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@5683f8
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922
    network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_201/lib/ext/sunec.jar, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://my-site.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_201/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, version: null]
    security: Loading SSL Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\security\cacerts
    security: Loaded SSL Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\security\cacerts
    security: Obtain certificate collection in SSL Root CA certificate store
    security: Obtain certificate collection in SSL Root CA certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: Loaded blacklisted.certs file: C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklisted.certs
    security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 1FC0E889AFEA322E6B71DB8BEBD02F86CA3F4B93BB772A0544911E7D611FA1B5
    security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 973A41276FFD01E027A2AAD49E34C37846D3E976FF6A620B6712E33832041AA6
    security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: Checking if SSL certificate is in Deployment permanent certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
    security: OCSP Response: GOOD
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
    security: OCSP Response: GOOD
    security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    network: ResponseCode for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 : 200
    network: Encoding for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 : null
    network: Server response: (length: 15333, lastModified: Mon Jan 21 10:15:24 EET 2019, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/java-archive)
    network: Downloading resource: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
        Content-Length: 15,333
        Content-Encoding: null
    network: Wrote URL https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 to File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache935836637493273617.tmp
    security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
    security: blacklist: Reconstruct cache
    security: blacklist: created: NEED_CREATE, lastModified: 1548066212673
    security: blacklist: check contains esOBJLzwpYxArxuni3f54/WHl+Jmi2EsiVyuwAwHbCc=, state now NEED_CREATE
    security: blacklist: check raw C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklist.dynamic, false
    security: blacklist: check raw C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\security\blacklist, false
    security: blacklist: check raw C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklist, false
    security: blacklist: save cache to C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\security\blacklist.cache
    security: blacklist: check contains esOBJLzwpYxArxuni3f54/WHl+Jmi2EsiVyuwAwHbCc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
    security: Trusted libraries list file not found
    security: blacklist: check contains esOBJLzwpYxArxuni3f54/WHl+Jmi2EsiVyuwAwHbCc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    security: blacklist: check contains esOBJLzwpYxArxuni3f54/WHl+Jmi2EsiVyuwAwHbCc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    network: Disconnect connection to https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    network: Downloaded https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache935836637493273617.tmp
    cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@eb2b4ba5: 1
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    security: Grant connect perm for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766 : java.security.Permissions@1c518b1 (
     ("java.net.URLPermission" "https://my-site.com:443/-" "*:*")
     ("java.net.URLPermission" "https://my-site.com:443" "*:*")
    )

    security: Expected Main URL: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    security: Loading Deployment certificates from C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
    security: Loaded Deployment certificates from C:\Users\User\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
    security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
    security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
    security: Timestamping info is available
    security: Start checking TSA certificate path
    security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
    security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
    security: The OCSP support is enabled
    security: The CRL support is enabled
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.digicert.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.digicert.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
    security: OCSP Response: GOOD
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.digicert.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
    security: OCSP Response: GOOD
    security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
    security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: The certificate was timestamped in valid period
    security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 08D7D1288EAA5824B1824246131B85348DFC3A4D9476418B0AA80605577D74CC
    security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 51044706BD237B91B89B781337E6D62656C69F0FCFFBE8E43741367948127862
    security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 3E9099B5015E8F486C00BCEA9D111EE721FABA355A89BCF1DF69561E3DC6325C
    security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 3E9099B5015E8F486C00BCEA9D111EE721FABA355A89BCF1DF69561E3DC6325C
    security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
    security: The OCSP support is enabled
    security: The CRL support is enabled
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.digicert.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
    security: OCSP Response: GOOD
    network: Connecting http://ocsp.digicert.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
    security: OCSP Response: GOOD
    security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
    security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
    security: Verifying permission attribute in main jar: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
    security: Timestamping info is available
    security: Start checking TSA certificate path
    security: The certificate was timestamped in valid period
    security: SSV validation:
        running: 1.8.0_201
        requested: null
        range: null
        javaVersionParam: null
        Rule Set version: null
    network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.201
    network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.201
    security: continue with running version
    security: JUT Record:
        plugin2
        https://my-site.com/Doc?dt=7458381155999161: launchjnlp= codebase_lookup=false code=pdfViewerApplet.PDFViewerApplet printallowed=true codebase=https://my-site.com/ progressbar=true width=854 archive=/Applets/PDFViewer/loaderapplet.jar?v=7766,/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 java_arguments=LVhteDUxMm0A browseallowed=false url=https://my-site.com/dochandler/file?dt=f0f950fc40fc45f6b7128c4642320f0c height=804  app_model=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
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://my-site.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922, version: null]
    network: Cache entry not found [url: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922, version: null]
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    network: ResponseCode for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 : 200
    network: Encoding for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 : null
    network: Server response: (length: 2279469, lastModified: Mon Jan 21 10:15:24 EET 2019, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/java-archive)
    network: Downloading resource: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922
        Content-Length: 2,279,469
        Content-Encoding: null
    network: Wrote URL https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 to File C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache6536774915285277590.tmp
    security: blacklist: check contains XKSetBrYXonRTC11oCiQZRZxazUd86naesuBayCY3hc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    security: blacklist: check contains XKSetBrYXonRTC11oCiQZRZxazUd86naesuBayCY3hc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    security: Trusted libraries list file not found
    security: blacklist: check contains XKSetBrYXonRTC11oCiQZRZxazUd86naesuBayCY3hc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    security: blacklist: check contains XKSetBrYXonRTC11oCiQZRZxazUd86naesuBayCY3hc=, state now IN_MEMORY
    security: blacklist: not  found in cache
    network: Disconnect connection to https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922
    network: Downloaded https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache6536774915285277590.tmp
    cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922
    cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@7878cbae: 1
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting http://my-site.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    security: Grant connect perm for https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 : java.security.Permissions@467fb8 (
     ("java.net.URLPermission" "https://my-site.com:443/-" "*:*")
     ("java.net.URLPermission" "https://my-site.com:443" "*:*")
    )

    security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922
    security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922
    security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
    security: Timestamping info is available
    security: Start checking TSA certificate path
    security: The certificate was timestamped in valid period
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
    security: Timestamping info is available
    security: Start checking TSA certificate path
    security: The certificate was timestamped in valid period
    basic: Applet loaded.
    basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
    basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 238467 us, pluginInit dt 30410100 us, TotalTime: 30648567 us
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "_ga=GA1.2.1486608597.1547820949; ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; _gid=GA1.2.1872343802.1548066135; .ASPXAUTH=DFHFDSFSDFD; update-token=true"
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    [....repeating the above many times here...]
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; .ASPXAUTH=SDFSDHFDSF; update-token=true; topbarsmallmenu=false"
    basic: Applet initialized
    basic: Starting applet
    basic: completed perf rollup
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/dochandler/file?dt=f0f950fc40fc45f6b7128c4642320f0c with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/dochandler/file?dt=f0f950fc40fc45f6b7128c4642320f0c with cookie "ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; .ASPXAUTH=SDFSDHFDSF; update-token=true; topbarsmallmenu=false"
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; .ASPXAUTH=SDFSDHFDSF; update-token=true; topbarsmallmenu=false"
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=DIRECT
    network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with cookie "ASP.NET_SessionId=tgsmzpfbzw4iygp24ojjy41s; .ASPXAUTH=SDFSDHFDSF; update-token=true; topbarsmallmenu=false"
    basic: Applet made visible
    basic: Applet started
    basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Notice the multiple network hits at the end for :

```
 network: Connecting https://my-site.com/Applets/PDFViewer/MainS.jar?v=5922 with proxy=
```

In other environments it seems to work fine (the same applet and on the same browser).
Has anyone seen anything like this?
Any ideas what is going wrong?

Note: The JAR files are downloaded without a problem from the browser.

Comment: why do you still use applets? they've been obsolete for quite some years now. They are no longer being supported by the major browsers, so they're pretty useless anyway.

Comment: @Stultuske If it was up to me I wouldn't use them. But we depend on applets for some extreme cases that web technologies cannot help enough.

Comment: what browser is it, and which version of the browser?

Comment: Latest version of IE11. But from my understanding it is the Java runtime downloading the JARs, so I thought that the problem is there to begin with. I am not sure what trigger this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by the server adding the header `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`.

This seems to make Java do crazy things...

I was also using the `deployJava.js` library, but I doubt that makes any difference.